# How to link powershell "-Name" in VPNClient

Tags: windows, powershell, vpn

I am creating a VPN in Powershell.

I want to get information on this VPN with `-AllEuserConnection`,but when trying to displaying by `-Name` I get an error. I tried many variations of the name but with no success. I need to access by name to do another command on the VPN.

Here is the example of the error I am getting:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Add-VpnConnection -Name "USERVPN" -ServerAddress "123.456.789.123" -TunnelType L2tp -AuthenticationMethod Pap -EncryptionLevel Optional -L2tpPsk "UserKey" -Force -AllUserConnection
WARNING: The currently selected encryption level requires EAP or MS-CHAPv2 logon security methods. Data encryption will
 not occur for Pap or Chap.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection

Name                  : USERVPN
ServerAddress         : 123.456.789.123
AllUserConnection     : True
Guid                  : {8119DEDB-B9C1-4660-B3EA-5F14B0B2205D}
TunnelType            : L2tp
AuthenticationMethod  : {Pap}
EncryptionLevel       : Optional
L2tpIPsecAuth         : Psk
UseWinlogonCredential : False
EapConfigXmlStream    :
ConnectionStatus      : Disconnected
RememberCredential    : False
SplitTunneling        : False
DnsSuffix             :
IdleDisconnectSeconds : 0


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-VpnConnection -Name "USERVPN"
Get-VpnConnection :  VPN connection USERVPN was not found. : The system could not find the phone book entry for this
connection.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-VpnConnection -Name "USERVPN"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (USERVPN:root/Microsoft/...S_VpnConnection) [Get-VpnConnection], CimExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VPN 623,Get-VpnConnection
```

Comment: The examples in the documentation use ```-Name``` *and* ```-AllUserConnection``` together - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/vpnclient/get-vpnconnection?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-3-get-a-specific-vpn-connection-from-the-global-phone-book. You could try ```Get-VpnConnection -Name "USERVPN" -AllUserConnection``` and see if that works. The difference is it reads from the *global* phone book instead of the user’s *local* phone book (based on what I just read, anyway - I’ve never actually used the cmdlet :-)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `Add-VpnConnection` Cmdlet you're using the switch parameter `-AllUserConnection`, so you need to call it on the `Get-VpnConnection` also.

```
Add-VpnConnection -Name "USERVPN" -ServerAddress "123.456.789.123" -TunnelType L2tp -AuthenticationMethod Pap -EncryptionLevel Optional -L2tpPsk "UserKey" -Force -AllUserConnection
Get-VpnConnection -Name USERVPN -AllUserConnection
```

You also need to call it on other Cmdlets, like `Remove-VpnConnection`.
Tested here:

[image]